# Old version of gcc for new Ubuntu

Tags: apt, gcc, backport

Is there a repository containing packages for old versions of gcc, for the latest Ubuntu. I want to install gcc3 alongside gcc 4, for programs that need gcc3 specifically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Or alternatively to the Debian snapshots Elazar posted in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu/39629#39629), you can use the Ubuntu package repositories for the older Ubuntu releases: http://packages.ubuntu.com

Add them to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` as Elazar already described:

```
deb     http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
```

The Hardy Universe repository is the one that contains gcc-3.4.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [debian snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org). Add the following lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb     http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20070730T000000Z/ lenny main
deb-src http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20070730T000000Z/ lenny main
deb     http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20070730T000000Z/ lenny/updates main
deb-src http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20070730T000000Z/ lenny/updates main
```

Now do

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install g++-3.4
```

And you're set!

This works for many other old packages, make sure you select the correct timestamp, look for the correct one at snapshots.debian website.

Comment: I get this [error](http://askubuntu.com/q/547048/135763) after installing and trying to compile a program. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @Phani not sure. Did you install all g++-3.4's dependencies?

Comment: How do I do that? I installed `build-essential` using apt-get.

Comment: Add the debian snapshot repository. You might want to check out a tutorial how to add repositories to debian.

Comment: What happened after you followed the steps in the answer?

Comment: @Phani did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich How did you know that 'lenny' is the correct name? Is there a way to match the desired version with the corresponding debian name?

Answer (score 6):

You can add gcc-4.4 (or any version between 4.4 and 8) on Ubuntu 16.04 via the  ([Toolchain test builds PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test))

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install gcc-4.4
```

As an aside, if you need to emulate gcc-4.4 on RH6, build your target program with

```
make CC="gcc-4.4 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE"
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work on modern ubuntu, apt can't find any new gcc versions, other then those available before.

Answer (score 3):

For 4.2.3 I had to add

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-security main
```

to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

[Reference1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1652053), [Reference2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/amd64/g++-4.2/download)

Answer (score 3):

For GCC 3.4 the correct source url is as below, since the old ones are moved into old-releases.ubuntu.com.
Thanks to @Ignitor for the main pointer

edit

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

for breezy, dapper, edgy, feisty, gutsy, hardy etc

```
    deb     http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
    deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
```

from xenial

```
    apt update
    apt install gcc-3.4
```

Answer (score 2):

gcc-3.3 is available in all current stable releases (In lucid, it is available in lucid-backports)

[List of binaries available per release](http://paste.ubuntu.com/879877/)

You can see the above list with the following commands:

Source package list:

```
rmadison gcc-3.3
```

Source and binary list:

```
rmadison gcc-3.3 -S
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to install the old GCC versions on Bionic (18.04).

For GCC 4.4 and 4.6:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main'
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe'
sudo apt install gcc-4.4 gcc-4.6
```

For GCC 4.7 and 4.9:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main'
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe'
sudo apt install gcc-4.7 gcc-4.9
```

And GCC 4.8 is already available:

```
sudo apt install gcc-4.8
```

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu 18.04, I did:

```
sudo apt install gcc-opt
```

to install gcc-3.3, gcc-3.4, and gcc-4.0

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-opt

Comment: This package only installs symlinks named gcc-3.3, gcc-3.4, and gcc-4.0.