# How to downgrade gcc to version 4.1.1 if I use Ubuntu 11.10 or 12.04 64-bit?

Tags: 64-bit, gcc

It may seems simlar to this question:
[Old version of gcc for new Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu)

but I can't solve it with the method provided in that thread

I get some error like

```
gcc-4.1 : Depends: cpp-4.1 (= 4.1.2-27ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
```

can someone tell me how to do it?

thanks

Comment: Remove cpp and try again :-)

Comment: to  Vitalie Ciubotaru , if I try to remove cpp ( version 4.6) , then I will need to remove a lot of softwares, this doesn't seem good

Comment: That is true. If you want to downgrade gcc, a bunch of other packages will need to be downgraded, too. In general, there's no good mechanism to downgrade packages. The only way is to remove the new ones and to install them again indicating the desired versions (as advised in the answer below http://askubuntu.com/a/146264/64668).

Comment: You can't with the version of Ubuntu that you have.

Answer (score 0):

to downgrade a package the command we have is

```
sudo apt-get install <pkg_name=its version>
```

so for your case

```
sudo apt-get install gcc=4.1.1
```

after installing older version of gcc, use update-alternatives --config to switch to it

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

then select the number corresponding to the version you want to switch to

Comment: I have try this, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I always use **Synaptic Package Manager** to fix such issues. Using it you can forcefully install other version of packages.

- Fist install synaptic package manager if you don't have already installed:

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install synaptic
  ```
- Then open synaptic package manager -> click **Custom Filters** down-left -> click **Broken** top-left, it will list all broken packages try to fix all broken packages. Also if any residual packages are there on more option you will get as **residual packages**.
  -Search for packages you want to **downgrade/upgrade**, highlight it by simply clicking on it **do not mark(tick)**, chose **Package** from the menu -> **Force Version** and chose some other versions from the list. Then click **Apply** to install it.
- Try to install again using command line.

Hope it works for you.