# How can I install gcc 3.3, g++ 3.3, cpp 3.3?

Tags: package-management, versions, unsupported-packages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Old version of gcc for new Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu)

I am trying to follow the directions for installing the Dyna language in Ubuntu, here:

http://dyna.org/wiki/index.php?title=Download

However, this requires installing very old versions of gcc, g++, and cpp. These versions no longer appear in the Ubuntu repositories. Is there a repository I should add to get older versions of the software? Or is there a better way to get these packages?

Comment: I would consider updating the code so that it builds properly instead.

Answer (score 0):

From the link above, make note of the **Ubuntu tips** towards the bottom of the screen.  You will need to modify the **lib/Makefile.config** file as noted to reflect the versions you have installed and recompile it.  You can also resort to downloading the compiled package, **dyna-0.3.9-1_i386.deb**, and running the file to install which would not require you to compile from source.

Comment: I saw the ubuntu tips; the questions is how to follow get versions 3.3 of those packages in the first place.

(I didn't notice the .deb file in the download list, but it doesn't work anyway! Still, thanks for mentioning.)