# How to install gcc 4.6.3 on 12.10?

Tags: installation, 12.10, gcc, compiler

I want to install a previous version of `gcc` to make Intel compilers work correctly.

Can I use `apt-get` to install? If so, which repository should I use?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Old version of gcc for new Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu)

Comment: using " sudo apt-get remove gcc" just broke up my bumblebee/optimus installation, days of work. use it with caution.

Answer (score 4):

I removed gcc (4.7) and install gcc-4.6. I actually don't think that the first step is necessary here, you might just be able to have gcc 4.7 and 4.6 installed alongside.

```
 sudo apt-get remove gcc
 sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6 g++-4.6
 sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 /usr/bin/gcc
 sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.6 /usr/bin/g++
```