# How I can install g++ 4.7.2?

Tags: gcc

Hi I need to install g++ version 4.7.2, but every attempt It installed the latest version 4.7.3.
How I can do to install the version 4.7.2?

Thank you.

<sub>Translated from Spanish</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest downloading the `.deb` file from [debian snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/gcc-4.7/) and installing it from there. Otherwise if you want to install it from the `apt` repository, you should take a look at this [almost duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu) and follow the answer.