# Downgrade to GCC < v3.0

Tags: apt, repository, gcc

For some reason I have to downgrade my GCC to version 2.x using apt-get (not downloading and compiling the source)

Is that possible? If yes, how can I find the repository address and install it via apt-get?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to check, GCC 2.x is very old, are you sure this is what you mean/need ?

Comment: @NGRhodes Yes. I need gcc 2.x

Comment: Please specify the "specific reason". maybe we can solve the root cause instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Not using apt-get, GCC 2.x predates Ubuntu !

I managed to locate GCC 2.95 at http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-2.95/
You could download the appropriate version and install using the `dpkg -i pathto/filename.deb` command. Who knows if it will work, or have any issues with dependencies and then you would for sure need to use apt-pinning to prevent Ubuntu installing a more modern version - really not worth even trying IMHO.

Comment: Can I add this debian repository you mentioned in my repositories list?

Comment: I don't know - I suspect the associated repositories are no longer active, this is just a file archive.

Comment: I found something else here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu

Comment: What do you think? Can this solution address the issue?

Comment: Yes it could, take note of my warnings on dependencies etc..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I use this debian snapshots, I face with KEYEXPIRED error! How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you are entering in a private hell.
Since GCC 2.x *predates Ubuntu* the risk is to hang somehow the system.

Have you considered to install Virtualbox in your Ubuntu machine and an old image of linux compatible with GCC 2.x? It's possible to [download even a pre installed images](http://virtualboxes.org/images/) of such kind of systems *ready to use*.

Since a program that requires GCC 2.x is rather old, probably it will not suffer to run in an emulated environment, and you can share part of the file system between the virtual machine and the Ubuntu host.