# How to install old version of gcc on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gcc

I need to install gcc 3.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to compile sources but it throws error. Is possible to install gcc 3.0 from repository? How to do that?

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu) does not work for me. `apt-get update` command throws this:

```
W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/universe/source/Sources
 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/universe/binary-amd64/Packages
 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/universe/binary-i386/Packages
 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or
old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Question was edited. I would like to install gcc from repository so compillation errors are not necessary.

Comment: Check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu

Comment: This link is in my question.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Please post an answer if you did. I need the same thing.

Comment: I did not resolve this.