# How do I install gcc-4.6 on Ubuntu 15.10 (32bit edition)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, gcc

When I try to install gcc-4.6 on Ubuntu15.10 (32bit edition) using apt-get, but I can't.

I tried it, but Ubuntu displayed these error messages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package g++-4.6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Where can I find "another source"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Old version of gcc for new Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu)

Comment: Haplo's answer will work too, you just need change the PPA entry to use `trusty` instead of `wily`.

Comment: @muru thanks a lot. I'll try to write my own PPA if I have time to learn about PPA. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added 2 lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb     http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe  
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
```

It seems to work fine.
Solved.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://launchpad.net/~h-rayflood/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-upper) the PPA link is at the bottom. Not sure how safe this is but I've added random PPA's and had no issues.

Comment: I doesn't work in my environment. Aftest "sudo apt-get update" I got the error message below.


W: Failed to fetch launchpad.net/~h-rayflood/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-upper/dists/wily/… HttpError404
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I have installed 32bit versioin of Ubuntu 15.10 because of project restrictions. This error message seems to be end of support of older version 32bit gcc.

Thanks!