# How to install app from older Ubuntu repository on a new Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I want to install a package on 16.04 but it's available on the 14.04 repos only. How do I do that?

I know it would work in 16.04 because I actually have it on a 16.04 that was upgraded from a 14.04 and it's working fine.

[*It's actually a game. It's very nice.*](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sweeper3d/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Old version of gcc for new Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu)

Comment: You might have to pin `trusty` to a low score (less than 500): http://askubuntu.com/a/103338/158442, but I think it won't be necessary when using an older repo.

Comment: @muru is there a way to just temporarily specify the repo I want to install the package from? Instead of adding the whole 14.04 repo to my repo list? thx

Comment: also I don't understand the low score part @muru

Comment: You can download the package file from http://packages.ubuntu.com and install it manually, but I don't think you can specify a new repository as a command line option or something.

Comment: that was my first thought but I can't find it @muru

Comment: While you search for a method to get it on 16.04, you can play it here: http://davidgoemans.com/Sweeper3D/ and you can get it for android here:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgoemans.Sweeper3D.

Comment: @SamuelSantana thank you but I'm actually more interested in knowing how to grab just a package from a specified repo

Comment: [Related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1005643), with a partial solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two cases:

### Installing a Snap package

If the application is found on [apps.ubuntu.com](https://apps.ubuntu.com/), now renamed to [snapcraft.io](https://snapcraft.io/), then it's a "Snap" package that is independent of the version of Ubuntu you want to install it on. You can install it with the "Ubuntu-Software" application on Ubuntu 16.04 and later. Or alternatively from the command line as follows:

```
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```

Snap packages are not real software packages, as they come with a redundant version of all kinds of dependencies, which makes them much larger. Also each Snap package uses its own ugly `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/…` mountpoint, which will show up when listing mounted file systems with `mount`, for example. So whenever a package is also available as a normal Ubuntu `.deb` package, better proceed to the next option:

### Installing a `.deb` package from an earlier release

If the application is found with a search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/), it's a real Ubuntu `.deb` package. To install it in a distribution where it is not (yet) available, go to the package's page in the latest distribution where it *is* available ([random example](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/net/quicksynergy)). Scroll down to the "Download [packagename]" table and click on the correct link in the "Architecture" column, which is usually the `amd64` one. Save the file, and then install it in the command line as follows:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install ./packagename_[version]_amd64.deb
```

This will automatically install all dependencies as long as they are available in your own release of Ubuntu, which is often the case. The `./` in the command above, or a full path to the file, is important because otherwise `apt` would look for the package in the repository, where it's not found for your release in this case.

(As for Sweeper 3D, it seems the package was simply pulled from the Snap repository, perhaps by the author himself. It is no longer available for any Ubuntu distribution.)