# Dependencies to install old .deb file

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and I have an old `.deb` file that I'm trying to install.  The Ubuntu Software app failed to install it, so I did `sudo dpkg -i headoverheels_1.0.1-1_amd64.deb`

This resulted in:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of headoverheels:
   headoverheels depends on liballegro4.2 (>= 2:4.2.2); however:
   Package liballegro4.2 is not installed.
   headoverheels depends on libxerces-c28; however:
   Package libxerces-c28 is not installed.
```

But `liballegro4.2` does appear to be available, so I tried `sudo apt-get install liballegro4.2-dev`. However -

```
Note, selecting 'liballegro4-dev' instead of 'liballegro4.2-dev'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  liballegro4.4 libjpgalleg4.4
The following NEW packages will be installed
  liballegro4-dev liballegro4.4 libjpgalleg4.4
```

Older versions of liballegro are available from https://pkgs.org/download/liballegro4.2-dev but the oldest (for Ubuntu 14.04) is also version 4.4.

What is the best approach here?

The original deb file was marked as 'for Ubuntu 10.04' so can I obtain the deb files for `liballegro4.2` and `libxerces-c28` from the Lucid repository somehow? (I'd prefer to have the deb files to keep, so I can install this program again in the future on a different machine)

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888042/how-to-install-app-from-older-ubuntu-repository-on-a-new-ubuntu) deals with installing older packages that are listed on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com), but that only goes as far back as 14.04.

Comment: What is your current Ubuntu version?

Comment: @N0rbert 18.04.  I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install binary version you need to get many dependencies manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-3_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xerces-c2/libxerces-c28_2.8.0+deb1-3build1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/allegro4.2/liballegro4.2_4.2.2-3_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libicu52_52.1-3_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libxerces-c28_2.8.0+deb1-3build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./liballegro4.2_4.2.2-3_amd64.deb
```

and then install the game:

```
wget http://www.headoverheels2.com/descargas/headoverheels_1.0.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./headoverheels_1.0.1-1_amd64.deb
```

Launch it with `headoverheels` command.