# What's the best way to install packages from older Ubuntu releases than the one I'm running?

Tags: apt

I'm running 17.10 artful, and I want to install [PSPP](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=pspp), which doesn't have a release for 17.10. What's the best way to install a different version (e.g. the one for 16.04)?

Comment: I would suggest build from source if possible as mixing different version usually is a bad idea!

Comment: PSPP is in both 17.04 and 18.04. Do you *really* want to install a 2-year-old 16.04 version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Old version of gcc for new Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu)