# ns2 installation problem in ubuntu

Tags: ns2

I have gcc-7.2.0 I want to install ns2.35 which requires gcc-4.4.
How to solve this problem. I have tried many commands and have downloaded Gcc4.4 tar file.

please help me for solving this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Old version of gcc for new Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu)

Comment: I'm referring to [richud’s answer](/a/983457/175814) specifically. All the other answer suggest the inclusion of package repositories from old releases which is a Bad Idea™ without proper package priority rules to accompany.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that ns2 v2.35 is available in the package repositories of all supported Ubuntu releases. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you for replying. but i didn't understand what to do for successfull installation

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsb_release -a`, `grep -Fe universe /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}`, `sudo apt-get update`, and `sudo apt-get -f install ns2`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply install the [`ns2` package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ns2) from Canonical’s package repository.<sup>1</sup> It comes in version 2.35 for all currently supported Ubuntu releases. You need to [enable the *Universe* repository](/q/148638/175814), if you haven't done so yet, to access this packages.

<sup>1</sup> As always you can use your favourite package manager to install the `ns2` package, e. g. Software Center, GNOME Software, Synaptic or the Apt command-line interface (`sudo apt install ns2`).

Comment: sir, can you further help me what steps I have to do?

Comment: Did you enable the Universe repository? Did you install the `ns2` package successfully? (Do you know how to install packages at all?)

Comment: sir, i have downloaded ns2 package from this link and enabled universe repository. please tell me the next steps.

Comment: Makefile:93: recipe for target 'mdart/mdart_adp.o' failed
make: *** [mdart/mdart_adp.o] Error 1
Ns make failed!

Comment: I don't know sir.

Comment: please help me "How to install correctly?"

Comment: How did you get `make` output from a package installation. This is confusing. Could you please edit your question to explain what *exactly* you did and what happened as a result?

Comment: sir first I extracted this package and copied it to ns2.35 all in one. then edited line no. 137 to "this->" in link state and then used "./install" command

Comment: Sir, Overall tell me the complete ns2.35 installation steps. currently my ubuntu version is 17.10

Comment: The complete installation steps are in the answer: 1) Enable the Universe repository, if not done yet, as described in the answer(s) to the linked question and 2) install the `ns2` package via the Apt package manager, e. g. with the command `sudo apt install ns2`. This is exactly what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: »» `tell me the complete ns2.35 build steps` «« : Please see my answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023978/ns2-compilation-errror-in-ubuntu

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!