# NS2 compilation errror in ubuntu

Tags: gcc, ns2

```
gcc-4.4 -c -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -DUSE_SHM -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I. -I/home/akhil/ns-allinone-2.35/include -I/home/akhil/ns-allinone-2.35/include -I/home/akhil/ns-allinone-2.35/include -I/include  otcl.c
make: gcc-4.4: Command not found
Makefile:91: recipe for target 'libotcl.a' failed
make: *** [libotcl.a] Error 127
otcl-1.14 make failed! Exiting ...
See http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-problems.html for problems
```

Comment: Please provide more information! Environment, build steps, etc...

Comment: `gcc-4.4: Command not found` is pretty self explanatory

Comment: @Akhil, please do not use old instructions for ns2. Plenty of posts in the "ns2 Forums" dated 2017 or 2018 ... with the latest news / suggestions / instructions → https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/ns2/ ... and https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ns-users ... and http://network-simulator-ns-2.7690.n7.nabble.com/ns-users-f3.html

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

"ns2" is usually built from source code, when you want to add an extra protocol. All ~300 patches (extra protocols) https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2lWZDBRSW40Q00?usp=sharing

'ns-2.35' Ubuntu 17.10 example: `sudo apt install g++-5` → I.e. no later than g++-5 (<=5.4) can be used. Note : You can have as many gcc versions as you want, installed at the same time.

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz           // 2014 - 2017 update  → →
```

→ https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
export CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 && ./install
                   // if Ubuntu 16.04, the build command is './install' only
cd ns-2.35/
sudo make install
```

The ~2500 simulations https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

It is packaged. Packaged means you do not need to compile it. There is [version  2.35 in the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=ns2).

Just run `sudo apt-get install ns2`.

Take the rule to firstly search binary packages, Snaps, Flatpaks and only if they are not found - compile.