# how to totally uninstall network simulator (ns2) and reinstall

Tags: networking, nas, adhoc, ns2

When configured, ns found the right version of tclsh in /usr/bin/tclsh8.6
but it doesn't seem to be there anymore, so ns will fall back on running the first tclsh in your path. The wrong version of tclsh may break the test suites. Reconfigure and rebuild ns if this is a problem.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: You can have as many ns-allinone-2.xx as you want, installed at the same time https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCjn-9fkR7tKeqClUpHsleaEdnoKRZzq/view?usp=sharing ... Build example, Ubuntu 17.10 .. 18.xx https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023978/ns2-compilation-errror-in-ubuntu → my answer.