# NS2 Software compilation issue in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, application-development, gcc, ns2

I tried to build and compile NS2 source code in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS distribution but I get back that message:

make: ***  No rule to make the target « mit/rca/rcagent.c », necessary for « mit/rca/rcagent.o ». Stop.
Ns make failed!

Someone has an idea about issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NS2 compilation errror in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023978/ns2-compilation-errror-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Not a duplicate, `mit/rca/rcagent.*` is found in the `MIT-leach` only. .... @RA AM, please update / edit your question to include ns2 version. ... Build instructions, 18.04 : https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/leach-in-ns2-35-with-ubuntu-18-04-lts-4175652235/#4 .... ns2-INFO https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCjn-9fkR7tKeqClUpHsleaEdnoKRZzq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay, I'm going to follow linuxquestions.org forum, and will update situation with ns2 and leach recompile.