# NS2 Installation in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ns2

I was trying to install ns2 from source. I followed the steps given here https://www.nsnam.com/2018/06/installation-of-ns2-in-ubuntu-1804.html.

I am getting the following error.
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating dltest/Makefile
config.status: creating tclConfig.sh
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-gcc
Makefile:1601: warning: overriding recipe for target '/home/sathvik/Documents/ns2'
Makefile:1514: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '/home/sathvik/Documents/ns2'
Makefile:1603: warning: overriding recipe for target '/home/sathvik/Documents/ns2'
Makefile:1601: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '/home/sathvik/Documents/ns2'
Makefile:1605: warning: overriding recipe for target '/home/sathvik/Documents/ns2'
Makefile:1603: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '/home/sathvik/Documents/ns2'
make: Circular /home/sathvik/Documents/ns2 <- /home/sathvik/Documents/ns2 dependency dropped.
make: Circular implementation/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix/../macosx/configure <- /home/sathvik/Documents/ns2 dependency dropped.
make: *** No rule to make target 'implementation/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix/../macosx/configure.ac', needed by 'implementation/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix/../macosx/configure'.  Stop.
tcl8.5.10 make failed! Exiting ...
For problems with Tcl/Tk see http://www.scriptics.com

Can you please help me through this.
Thank you in advance

Comment: nsnam : https://www.nsnam.org/ is the original ns site. https://www.nsnam.com/ is a private student log / notes by Pradeep Kumar. ... `ns-2.35` HOWTO → https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023978/ns2-compilation-errror-in-ubuntu → My answer. Same commands for all Ubuntu´s 17.04 .. 18.04 ..19.04 . ... ns2-INFO https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCjn-9fkR7tKeqClUpHsleaEdnoKRZzq/view?usp=sharing