# Instal NS2 in Linux Ubuntu 32 bit

Tags: xubuntu, 32-bit, ns2

how to install NS2 on linux correctly. because many tutorials cannot be run. ask for help please yes because I'm still a beginner in using Linux Ubuntu. thank you.

Comment: Missing information : Please edit your question to include Ubuntu version. .... `ns-2.35` build example https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023978/ns2-compilation-errror-in-ubuntu → My answer.

Comment: You didn't give your release, but https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ns2 shows it's available for supported releases (listing i386 architecture which is x86 [32bit]).  ie. you only `sudo apt install ns2` and if you have 'universe' enabled it'll install; if you haven't installed 'universe' (default for Ubuntu flavors) see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/ns2/download

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give your release, but https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ns2 shows it's available for supported releases (listing i386 architecture which is x86 [32bit]).

ie. you only `sudo apt install ns2` and if you have 'universe' enabled it'll install

If you haven't enabled 'universe' see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  'universe' is enabled by default for Ubuntu flavors (such as Lubuntu, Xubuntu..), but it enables Ubuntu community software to be added to your system; by default Ubuntu uses only Canonical software which for a LTS release has 5 years of support; 'universe' or community support can be shorter (eg. 3 years is normal for LTS releases)

*I find packages.ubuntu.com really useful, not as quick as `apt-cache search` from terminal, but the web engine provides releases other than my own thus is really useful here, or anytime you have a browser already open*