# How to install gcc 6.3.0 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gcc

I am trying to install version 6.3.0 of gcc. I need that one in particular and I do not know how to do it. Since if I run "sudo apt-get install gcc" it updates me to the latest version (7.4) and it does not work for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Probably already answered here: https://askubuntu.com/q/39628/459652 (If not, [edit] and explain why.)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410723/255251

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has gcc 6.4 in the package `gcc-6`, which can be installed with `sudo apt install gcc-6`. Later, you can call it with `gcc-6`

Answer (score 0):

For getting gcc version 6.3.0, first you've to download the source:

```
wget https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/archive/gcc-6_3_0-release.tar.gz
```

Then extract it:

```
tar xvzf gcc-6_3_0-release.tar.gz
```

Then install it according to their [official documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html).

Comment: Could you tell me what commands to enter to install it? I am new with this operating system and I do not understand the official documentation well... Thank you very much anyway

Comment: Tarballs are recommended only for those who already have some skills. If, as a beginner, you insist upon specific versions and complex install methods, then you may find your learning curve to be frustrating. .tar.gz files usually include a README file and an INSTALL file. Read them.

Comment: I don't know how to do... 
I'm very desperate I can not install the compiler. Help me please

Comment: Yeah, useless answer.

Answer (score 0):

First check what versions of gcc are offered from the standard repositories:

```
apt-cache pkgnames |egrep gcc-[0-9]*$
```

If you see the one you want, just install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-6
```

To run this version of gcc (different than the system default) for your project, you may:

1. Set up an alias (alias gcc=/bin/gcc-6) either in a script specific to your project or in your .bashrc file.
2. Put in a gcc link in your bin directory to override the system gcc found later in your PATH.
3. Put the project's bin directory early in your PATH, and put a link to gcc there.  This location may also be the appropriate one for a gcc verion not supplied from the standard repositories.  Add the executables for the old gcc to the project specific bin.

Do NOT alter the update-alternatives for the gcc compiler to change the system default to the different gcc version. The system was build with a specific compiler version, and expects that version to be available when needed for kernel modules updates.  Search this site for "update broke my computer" to see the consequences of a video module which fails to compile.